# Need to run a stored procedure on all non system databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to loop through all non system databases and run a stored procedure. This stored procedure exists in all of the user databases.

This is what I have found so far:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = ''U'' ORDER BY name' 

USE @command;
GO

EXECUTE Support.CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase;
GO
```

I get an error this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '@command'.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'Support.CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase'.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Have a look at Aaron Bertrand's [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
DECLARE @spName VARCHAR(50)
SET @spName = 'Support.CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase'

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 
BEGIN 
    USE ? 
        IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.procedures AS P WHERE p.name = ''' + @spName + ''')
        BEGIN
            PRINT ''running '+ @spName + ' on '' + DB_NAME()
            EXEC ' +@spName+' 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            PRINT ''' + @spName + ' was on found on database '' + DB_NAME()''
        END

END ' 

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

It will run on all non-system databases.
Now, the error you get means that SQL Server cannot find the stored procedure. You could fix this by creating the stored procedure on any database that does not have it yet and then running it. 
So a better query would be

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
DECLARE @schemaName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @spName VARCHAR(50)
SET @schemaName  = 'Support'
SET @spName = 'CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase'

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 
BEGIN 
    USE ? 

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 
                        FROM sys.procedures AS P 
                            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = P.schema_id
                        WHERE p.name = ''' + @spName + '''
                            AND s.name = ''' + @schemaName + ''')
        BEGIN
            PRINT ''creating '+ @spName + ' on '' + DB_NAME()
            IF NOT EXISTS (   SELECT TOP 1 1
                  FROM   sys.schemas AS S
                  WHERE  S.name = ''' + @schemaName + ''' )
                BEGIN
                    PRINT ''CREATING SCHEMA ' + @schemaName + '''
                    EXEC ( '' CREATE SCHEMA ' + @schemaName + ''' );
                END;

                EXEC ( ''
                    CREATE PROCEDURE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @spName + '
                    AS
                    BEGIN  
                        -- SP CODE GOES HERE
                        -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.TABLES --uncomment this for check
                    END 
                '' );
        END

        PRINT ''running '+ @spName + ' on '' + DB_NAME()
        EXEC ' + @schemaName + '.' + @spName +' 

END ' 

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: I'm getting `Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '` on the first example. I'm looking at the second one now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT 'USE [' + [name] + ']; EXECUTE Support.CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase;' 
        FROM [sys].[databases]
        WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

Comment: Am I to replace `STUFF` with the `Support.CleanIndiciesAndShrinkDatabase`? I'm not sure I understand this code honestly.

Comment: @TechGuy OK, just check the edit. No need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Create PROC PROC_NAME 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
declare @cursor cursor
set @cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR select name from sys.databases where database_id > 4

open @cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

DECLARE @use nvarchar(50) = 'USE '

SET @use = @use + @name


Declare @query nvarchar(max) = @use + ' exec Your_PROC'


EXEC sp_executesql  @query

FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @name 

END

CLOSE @cursor

DEALLOCATE @cursor

END
```